# SharePoint Online : Restore file deleted from Second Stage Recycle Bin

Tags: sharepoint-online

This is for a SharePoint Team Site on Office 365.
One of my user deleted a file from Site Assets, and also deleted it from Recycle Bin and Second Stage Recycle Bin.

I would like to know if there is a way to restore this file? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ram,

If the file/site was deleted not more than 20 days before, you can reach out to Microsoft support (open a ticket with them) and they will be able to restore the file/site for you.

I believe this is the only way to restore.

Answer (score 2):

Once the file is deleted from the `Second Stage Recycle Bin`, it can't be restored by any means.

**The available workaround** is to restore it back from any available site backup that has the same file.